# From a LDS perspective, when does the Holy Ghost get a Physical Body?

Tags: lds, pneumatology

I am looking for where we are told that the Holy Ghost gets a physical body.  I thought it was doctrine that He will get a physical body during the Millennium.  However, I am not able to find a reference.  I went through every verse which has the phrase "Holy Ghost" in the scriptures and did not find it.  Maybe I missed it.  Maybe I need to look at the verses which reference the Holy Ghost with a different name (e.g. the Spirit).  I could not find a reference on https://lds.org ... maybe I did not look long enough.  I see a few discussions on the Internet but no references.  Can you provide a reference which says when the Holy Ghost gets a physical body?

I am assuming that everyone (including the Holy Ghost) which chose Heavenly Father's plan will receive a physical body.  [D&C 130:22](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/130.22?lang=eng#21) shows us that He cannot perform his functions with a physical body.

Perhaps, I am totally wrong and the Holy Ghost will never receive a physical body.  If that is correct, please show me a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing in LDS canon about this, as far as I can tell. There are a [couple statements](https://www.fairmormon.org/archive/publications/ask-the-apologist-what-about-the-holy-ghost) from Joseph Smith that indicate that he felt the Holy Ghost would eventually receive a body, which I've copied from the linked article. The first is from the Encyclopedia of Joseph Smith’s Teachings:

> The Holy Ghost is yet a spiritual body and is waiting to take to himself a body, as the Savior did.

And the second is from the Words of Joseph Smith:

> The Holy Ghost is now in a state of probation which if he should perform in righteousness he may pass through the same or a similar course of things that the Son has.

You would have to check the referenced print sources to obtain more detail on the context of these quotations.

However, note that other general authorities have failed to confirm these statements as doctrine, and have stated that there is nothing authoritative on the matter (see [this link](https://www.fairmormon.org/answers/Question:_Will_the_Holy_Ghost_ever_receive_a_physical_body%3F)). Generally, a church leader, even Joseph Smith, making a couple of statements on a given topic doesn't automatically mean they are doctrine. In the case of Joseph Smith's recorded statements on the Holy Ghost receiving a body, we do not know if these statements are revelation or speculation.

Comment: I believe that church doctrine on resurrection, https://www.lds.org/topics/resurrection?lang=eng (4th paragraph), is that everyone will get a physical body; this lines up with Joseph Smith's statements and so can be considered doctrine

Comment: "they are interesting speculation", well, I wouldn't *quite* go that far. It could be speculation, or it could have been revelation. We just don't know.

Comment: @PyRulez That's a good point - I didn't mean to make that statement an assertion, but it reads like one. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Either after everyone else, or sometime after Christ comes again.

Either he is required until the very end and will be the very last of all God's children to receive a body, or he is only required until Christ (the second comforter) returns during the Millennium.

However, there is no firm answer. Bruce R. McKonkie said this in regards to the Holy Ghost:

> In this dispensation, at least, nothing has been revealed as to his
>   origin or destiny; expressions on these matters are both speculative
>   and fruitless *- (Mormon Doctrine)*

If the Holy Ghost is a spirit Child of God, just like everyone else, then he will be resurrected, just like everyone else. The only spirits who will never be resurrected are those who kept not their first estate; the sons of perdition.

If the Holy Ghost *is not* a child of God, then we have no idea who he is, where he came from, or why he is still a spirit. There is limited progression as a spirit, hence why we're all sitting here on earth in our mortal meat suits talking about spiritual matters on the internet. There is little reason to believe that he is not a child of God.

Comment: The official doctrine is that there is no official doctrine on the subject: we simply do not know whether the Holy Ghost will receive a physical body.  Statements such as "just like everyone else, then he will be resurrected" are unjustified by the Mormon canon.

Comment: @Joshua For as in Adam all die, even so in Christ shall all be made alive. The Earth was created so *all* God's children could receive a physical body. If the Holy Ghost is one on God's children then according to Mormon Doctrine there is no reason to assume he won't receive a body.

Comment: But what does "all" mean in that scripture you share?  It doesn't include the third part of the pre-mortal hosts that followed Satan and were cast out and will never receive a body.  So "all" can't mean "all of God's children".   It could mean, for example, "all people who have lived on Earth", which would exclude the Holy Ghost.

Comment: Also, is there any doctrine that the Holy Ghost is a son of God?  I can't think of any off the top of my head, and haven't been able to find any.  If there is some canon answer on this, I would be happy to hear it.